# How to execute a executable with sudo?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, command-line

I have an executable file but don't know what type or format it is. When I execute like this

```
$chmod +x xfile
$./xfile
```

It shows

```
Permission denied
```

when I run as super user

```
$sudo ./xfile
```

It shows

```
sudo: ./xfile: command not found
```

I am new to Linux please tell me how to execute it.

Comment: Try `sudo sh /path/to/file/xfile`

Comment: which type of executable is it? A python program, ruby or some binary ?

Comment: You are doing the right process to run the file. Nevertheless, in certain cases you must use sudo chmod -x xfile in order to create the proper execution permissions over the file itself. In addition you must consider the location of the file. If it belongs to a different hard disk drive/partition or usb-memory/external-storage the command may not succed giving the proper permissions to the file for execution. Good luck!

Comment: Once I was in trouble because I forgot the extension of the file. Did you put it?

Answer (score 3):

Strange, it works exactly that way over here.

First, try to find out what the file is:

```
file xfile
```

The file command looks inside the file and based on certain "magic" tries to figure out what that program does.

From what you describe I guess that it is a shell executable that tries to execute yet another program. If this is the case, why don't you post the code of the shell executable using http://paste.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. In my case the executable was stored on a different drive which was why chmod+x was not working.

I copied the executable to a Linux directory (like Desktop), set the permissions using chmod+x, ran the executable using "./" and it worked :)

Comment: yes, probably because of the reason in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unless the filesystem of the device is like `ext3` or `ext4`, (and probably it is FAT32 for you), the filesystem does not store much metadata about files, including the executable bit.

When you do `chmod +x yourfile`, then `ls -la yourfile`, you will notice the executable bit has not in fact been set.

The solution here is to `cp yourfile ~/yourfile; chmod +x ~/yourfile; ~/yourfile`, because the filesystem on which your Linux is installed has executable permissions.

[Learn more about the *nx permissions model](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions).